# SQL Server subquery/derived table update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-warehouse

I am trying to write an update statement that uses a derived table(?) in the `From` clause. This update statement needs to update 3 columns at once. The derived table selects the top 6 and orders them in desc order so that when I update them it selects the top 1 it is actually getting the 6th one (in other statements I'm getting the 1st, 2nd, 3rd...etc., I'm just writing the 6th now because they are all the same (more or less))

My problem is that I need to specify in the derived table "where" clause which set of 6 to grab. I have "t1.trace_ID = t2.trace_ID" but that will not work because t2 is outside of the subquery.

I need to find a way to determine which set of data to grab based on Trace_ID.

Any recommendations?

```
update t2
set RWK6_OPERATION_CODE = (select top 1 O_C.OPERATION_CODE),
    RWK6_REASON = (Select top 1 O_C.REWORK_REASON),
    RWK6_DATE = (Select top 1 o_C.OPERATION_CODE)
From plant.PIECE_DETAIL t2
inner join 
     (Select top 6 
              t1.TRACE_ID
             ,t1.OPERATION_CODE
             ,t1.REWORK_REASON
             ,t1.OPERATION_START_DATE_D 
      from app.OHCMS_ITEM_OPERATION_TRACE t1
      where *t1.TRACE_ID = t2.TRACE_ID*
      and  REWORK_REASON is not null
      order by OPERATION_START_DATE_D, OPERATION_START_TIME desc) as O_C 
on O_C.TRACE_ID = t2.TRACE_ID
Where t2.rwk_cycle > 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can phrase this as a `cross apply`:

```
From plant.PIECE_DETAIL t2 cross apply
     (Select top 6 t1.*
      from app.OHCMS_ITEM_OPERATION_TRACE t1
      where t1.TRACE_ID = t2.TRACE_ID and
            REWORK_REASON is not null and
            t1.TRACE_ID = t2.TRACE_ID
      order by OPERATION_START_DATE_D, OPERATION_START_TIME desc
     )  O_C 
Where t2.rwk_cycle > 5
```

This is subtly different, because it finds the matching rows in the subquery and *then* fetches the top 6.  Your original seemed to fetch the top 6 and *then* do the match.  I'm not sure which logic you really want, but you can achieve the original logic using an additional subquery or by moving the outer comparison to the `where` clause.